# Filtering using a comma separated list

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, tags

I've been developing a dynamic data frame in R Shiny, which is filtered depending on a number of user inputs (checkboxes, radio buttons, that kind of thing).  For one of the options, I am trying to filter the data frame based on a vector of distinct strings, though in the data frame they are stored as a single comma separated string.

```
         [,1]    [,2]                      
[1,] "Sam"   "C, Python, VB"           
[2,] "Jess"  "VB6, R"                  
[3,] "Mike"  "Matlab, Java, Javascript"
[4,] "Sarah" "Python"                  
[5,] "Ahmad" "HTML, Ruby"
```

Using this simplified example, I have a set of names and the programming languages they know.  I want the dataframe filtered to only include those who know Python or R.  My checkboxes pass the selections as a vector in the form

```
selections <-    c("Python", "R")
```

The result of filtering the dataframe with the selection vector should be

```
           [,1]    [,2]                      
[1,] "Sam"   "C, Python, VB"           
[2,] "Jess"  "VB6, R"                  
[3,] "Sarah" "Python"
```

Getting the filter to work is my main issue.

I've been converting the languages strings into vectors using

```
strsplit(as.character(df[,2]), split=", ")
```

And I can filter if the selection vector matches the dataframe's exactly, but not if it's only partially similar.

I was trying something along the lines of

```
df %>% 
      filter(Languages %in% selections)
```

But to no avail.  I also looked at using for loops, but those make me feel uneasy in R, like I'm angering the Gods of Vectorisation.

Is there something I'm missing?

**Edit 1**
Following lmo's advice using regular expressions, I managed to get it working.

Having "C++" as one of the selections caused some problems, so I had to replace it with an escaped version.

```
selections <- replace(selections, selections=="C++", "C\\+\\+")
```

I then collapsed selections into a | separated string for use in the regular expression

```
selections <- paste(selections, collapse = '|')
```

Finally, I put it into the lmo's suggestion

```
df <- df[grep(paste0("(^|, )(",
                               selections,
                               ")(,|$)"),
                  df$Programming.Languages),]
```

I'll put the actual code I used for the reactive Shiny expression, if I can figure out how to make it more compact ([like in](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302078/collapsible-code-markup))

**Edit 2**
Works with an HTML snippit (doen't run though)

```html
  # Filter the courses based on the language checkboxes
  ## A regular expression is used to filter

  courseData <- reactive({
df <- courses
# The +'s in C++ cause a problem in the regex, so it is replaced with an escaped version
selections <- replace(input$languages, input$languages=="C++", "C\\+\\+")
selections = paste(selections, collapse = '|')

# This selects courses in the data frame who offer the selected languages
## grep returns the row numbers
df <- df[grep(paste0("(^|, )(",
                           selections,
                           ")(,|$)"),
              df$Programming.Languages.Taught),]
  })
  
## The selections are made by selecting checkboxes, and the reactive expression is used later in the program
```

Comment: Please show us what you have worked on so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should accomplish what you are trying to do (subset to the rows containing R or python) in the second variable. Say your data is a matrix called myMat. Then try

```
myNewMat <- myMat[grep("(^|, )(R|Python)(,|$)", myMat[, 2]),]
```

Here, `grep` will return the positions (row numbers) of the elements in the second column that contain "R" or "Python" and not select substrings like "Ruby."

Note that the same code will work if myMat is a data.frame.

Comment: Thanks!  Would never have thought of using regular expressions.  I've amended my question to show how I implemented your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

We need to `unlist` the `list` obtained from `strsplit` to make it work.

```
df %>% 
   filter(Languages %in% unlist(selections))
```